# How to define Empty Char in Delphi

Tags: string, delphi, char

Just for curiosity,

Why in Delphi, if we defined an empty char by:

```
a:Char;
a:='';
```

we get an error: **Incompatible types: 'Char' and 'string'**

However, if we placed

```
a:='a';
```

it will be fine?

Is it necessary to define an empty char by: `a:=#0`?

Comment: In the .net world, you could have an "empty" Char because they have Nullable types (via their generics system). And in the database world, database fields can be Nullable, but all Delphi `Ordinal` types, including `Integer`, `Char`, `Byte`, and the rest, while they might have some sentinel (flag) or zero values (#0) for Char, for example, can not be "empty" or "null".  Since strings and arrays are not Ordinal types the rules are different. A string is like a "dynamic array of characters".

Comment: You are confused about `''` constant expression. It is of type `string` and not compatible with type `char`. In contrary `'a'` is compatible. So, you **have** to **define** "empty char" convention.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A char is a single (that is, exactly one) character. So 'a', '∫', and '⌬' are all OK, but not 'ab' (a two-character string), 'Hello World!' (a twelve-character string), or '' (a zero-character string).

However, the NULL character (#0) is a character like any other.

In addition, the character datatype is implemented as a word (in modern versions of Delphi), that is, as two bytes. If all these values 0, 1, ..., 2^16 - 1 are used for real characters, how in the world would you represent your 'empty char'?

Comment: u r right with the last edited phrase, I meant by empty char a null character, but i thought that when I place a:='', the compiler will take it as #0 by default, and didn't expect such error, so i wanted to know why is that. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Dorin We have to let it stew for 15 minutes first though, can't accept until time has passed

Comment: @Dorin u r right, i am just waiting to think about the answers to accept one, just like David said :)

Comment: @Zeina: Of course, the Delphi compiler could treat `''` synonymously with `#0`, but I would find that confusing. In addition, does it really take that much longer to write `#0` than `''`?

Comment: Delphi strings have a #0 (or widechar(0) aka #0#0 for utf16) after the end (so you can always pass them safely to legacy C systems), but can also contain #0.  The end #0 is not user adressable (since after the string, and [] is only valid for 1..length(s)), so the compiler assumes you want #0 as content.

Comment: @Marco: 'Legacy C systems'? The Windows API?

Comment: I was thinking about calls without "n" in it that rely on terminating #0 alone. But I was a bit wrong, since zero termination is still important for "n" versions if #0 comes before the max length.

Comment: I have always disliked that Delphi uses single quotes for both `Char` and `String` literals.  It may make coding easier, but it also causes confusion like this.  I use C++ primarily, and it uses single quotes for characters and double quotes for strings.  More explicit, and intuitive to me.

Comment: Confusion like what? The problem here is than an empty string has no equavalence in CHAR terms. It is not equal to #0, which is a Cism. It has nothing to do with quoting IMHO.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort It's more about clarity and explicitness for the reader of the code. Obviously there's no confusion for the compiler but anything that makes it easier for the human reader to parse is good.

Comment: If you mean the other thing: Refusing a string literal assignment to char is as clean as adding extra syntax for that. In both cases you get a compiler error. Choosing which one is taste.

Comment: Well, personally I think it is pretty easy to determine if a string literal has length 1 or not...

Comment: The problem with a:='', I believe, is that Delphi uses two single quotes together to escape the single quote literal. For example a:='''' sets a equal to one single quote. Therefore a:='' is like saying a:='; which is not legal syntax.

Comment: @JonathanElkins: No, that is not the case. `''` is simply the empty string, and it is perfectly legal to use that combination, like in `ShowMessage('')`. But the empty string consists of zero characters, so it is not a character.

Comment: @Andreas oh yes of course you are right I do that all the time. Though when I was trying to make a const declaration for a set like this MYSET = set of char ['A', 'B', 'C'] and i wanted to include a single quote in the set i had to do this ['A', 'B', 'C', ''''] leading to my last comment. Which seems silly now. I was getting an error message but it must have been because the null char I wanted also in the my set constant was, like you explained, not a CHAR.

Answer (score 20):

There is no such thing as an empty `char`. A `char` has to have a value. It is an ordinal type, a simple value type. Just as an integer, say, always has a value, so does a `char`.

The value `#0` is not an empty `char`, it is the character with value 0, commonly known as `NUL`.

Comment: In Pascal thats `ordinal` type.